# Cannot extend partition

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I am running out of space on the hard drive I am using for an AWS Ubuntu instance.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   12M   88M  12% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.3G  439M  95% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The lsblk command shows that I have a partition of 8gb on a 20gb volume.

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  20G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

When 
I try to extend the partition, I get an error saying it is already max size (2096891 * 4096 = 8.5gib).

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 2096891 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I don't think I need to extend the physical volume, but do I need to extend the logical volume? How can I get the partition to use more of the 20 gb volume?

Answer (score 0):

So the full steps are :

1. Extend the physical volume in AWS to 20 gb.
2. Determine if the file system is ext3/ext4 or xfs.

   sudo file -sL /dev/xvda1

   /dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ***ext4*** filesystem data, UUID=1233211232132123123, volume name "myig-roots" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
3. In this case it is a ext4 files system, so we use grow part

   sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1

Now the partition is extended:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  20G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  20G  0 part /
```

Here's a [link](https://blog.shikisoft.com/increase-root-volume-of-ebs-backed-ec2/) to something very similar.

Comment: I suggest you explain why this is in your answer. E.g., something along the lines of there being two steps: (1) expand partition; (2) expand filesystem